# Align framed environment boxes accurately

Tags: framed, layout

I'm trying to draw a figure consisting of two boxes, using the `framed` environment, aligned side by side, each containing a small header and an `align*` environment. I'd like some symmetry. I.E. that the top and bottom lines of the boxes line up and the boxes are of equal width and symmetrical about the center of the page.

This is what I've got so far (Making use of some shorthands in the `align` environments, but I'd like a solution that does not depend on the contents of the `align`s):

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{framed}
    \centering
    \textbf{Unit}

    \scalebox{.9}{\parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \begin{align*}
        \unit{A}:&\quad A \rightarrow \allEn\pstar A\\
        \unit{A}(\env)=&\quad\finpr{\Id{A(\env,e)}}{\e\in E}
    \end{align*}
    }}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{framed}
    \centering
    \textbf{Co-Unit}

    \scalebox{.9}{\parbox{\linewidth}{%
    \begin{align*}
        \counit{B} : &\quad \pstar\allEn B \rightarrow B\\
        \counit{B}(\env, \e') =&\quad \pi_{\e'} : \Pi_{e\in E}B(\env, \e)\rightarrow B(\env, \e')
    \end{align*}
    }}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}

\caption{The unit and co-unit of the adjunction}
    \label{UnitCoUnitDefinition}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Currently]

If you look carefully, these boxes aren't quite aligned vertically.

[image: Unaligned]

Is there a way to fix the size of the boxes to be equal regardless of the contents of the boxes?

Comment: (1) always post full minimal examples, not sniplets. (2) why would they be aligned when they do not have the same height?

Comment: Your issue seems related to `\finpr`, because [this definition](https://pastebin.com/raw/DYdL2Hac) provides [no difference between the two box heights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdvaN.png).

Comment: @Werner how bizarre - my definition is very similar but using `{\left\langle#1\right\rangle_{#2}}` instead. This appears to have fixed the issue as you've said. I'm currently deciding whether re-jig the question so it's useful for others (i.e. using an example with obviously different height aligns)

Comment: @Xandros: If you don't need `\left`...`\right`, don't just assume things will be the same without it.

Comment: Playing with a table could be a better choice here.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ti*k*Z to handle this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        draw,text centered,
        text width=.45\textwidth,
        minimum height=2.5cm,
        inner sep=0pt
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \tikz\node {%
    \textbf{Unit}
    \begin{align*}
        A&=B+C+D\\
        B\times C&=1+4
    \end{align*}};%
    \quad%
    \tikz \node {%
    \textbf{Co-unit}
    \begin{align*}
        A&=B+C+D\\
        B\times C&=1+4
    \end{align*}};%
    \caption{The unit and co-unit of the adjunction}
    \label{UnitCoUnitDefinition}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]